# Add a new columns in Pandas using if x=x then y*y

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, join

I have two dataframes which I would like to create a new columns based on data from the two dfs.

df1:

| CURR | RATE |
| --- | --- |
| USD | 1.25 |
| AUD | 1.30 |
| GBP | 1.50 |

df2:

| CURR | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| GBP | 123 |
| USD | 253 |
| AUD | 532 |

What I want is to add a new column to df 2 which will check if the "*CURR*" matches then multiplies the corrisponding rate by the value.

e.g. `new column = (if df1['CURR'] = df2['CURR'] then df1['RATE'] * df2['VALUE'])`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can first [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the two dataframes on the `CURR` field, then multiply `RATE` by `VALUE`:

```
merged = df1.merge(df2, on='CURR')
merged['OUT'] = merged['RATE'] * merged['VALUE']
```

Your "if condition" will be satisfied thanks to the merging operation.